# How to remove character syntax from a string

Tags: java, string, char

Run down:
In my program, I format custom text by having character values leading the text it is going to format.

The syntax is '§#' or '§somecharacter'.
Example:
    I have a string "Hello world!" but to make it underlined I do "§uHello World!" or to make it underlined and blue "§u§1Hello World!"

This is good for output but there are some times where I need to use "Hello World!" all by itself without the formatting syntax concatenated to the string.

The character '§' signifies format but the following character is unknown.

How would I remove all instances of '§' then the following character from the string?

Comment: try with `regex` --> `yourString = yourString.replaceAll("§.","");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shall do the job for you, considering only alphabat or numeral follows `§`

```
String str = "§u§1Hello World!";
str.replaceAll("§[a-z0-9]", "");
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. This was a simple and easy fix!

Comment: Glad that helped you.. have fun coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, String class is immutable so you cannot **remove** (but replace). So you can go for extracting a substring and then storing it in the same String object.
So if you have a string such as String str="§uHello World!", you can do

> str=str.substring(str.lastIndexOf('§')+2);

or

> str=str.replaceAll("§.{1}","");